# Unknown column ' ' in the field list mysql and passing dynamic table name while calling mysql function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was trying to create a mysql stored procedure function using mysql workbench, which will show result of join data of two tables on based on some conditions. I want to pass table names as parameter also.

My code is here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_Texts`(IN wrd longtext, IN dbname longtext,
 IN splitdbname longtext,
 IN lang longtext)


BEGIN
          
        
SET @sql_ = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',dbname,' as ifxcd

INNER JOIN 
',splitdbname,' as ifxsd
ON 
ifxsd.Crawl_id = ifxcd.Id where ifxsd.Language = ',lang,'

AND ifxsd.Word Like ',wrd,'%

order by ifxsd.Percentage desc 
limit 100');
          

PREPARE statement_ FROM @sql_;
          
EXECUTE statement_ ;

END
```

Call Function:

```
call Get_Texts('acc', emp_info, split_emp_txt , 'English(en)');
```

After calling the function I get an error

> 'Unknown column 'emp_info' in the field list

How can I overcome this and can see the desired output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `call Get_Texts('acc', 'emp_info', 'split_emp_txt' , 'English(en)');`. And quote inserted literals in CONCAT.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is a correction of course but the issue was in the syntax of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in syntax of the query as i found finally. Here is the correct code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Get_Texts`(IN wrd longtext, IN dbname longtext, 
IN splitdbname longtext, IN lang longtext)



BEGIN

SET @sql_ = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `",dbname ,"` as ifxcd
INNER JOIN `",splitdbname,"` as ifxsd ON ifxcd.id = ifxsd.Crawl_id 
where ifxsd.Language = '",lang,"' and ifxsd.Word Like '",wrd,"%'
ORDER BY ifxsd.percentage DESC
limit 100");
PREPARE statement_ FROM @sql_;
EXECUTE statement_ ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement_;
END
```

Call Procedure:

```
call Get_Texts('acc', 'emp_info', 'split_emp_txt' , 'English');
```

Answer (score 0):

SET a udv before the call and prefix emp_iinfo with an at symbol. same for split_emp_text
for example

```
set @emp_info = 'aaa';
set @split_emp_text = 'bbb'
call Get_Texts('acc', @emp_info, @split_emp_txt , 'English(en)');
```